# Differentiation question (quotient rule)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find $f'(x)$ if:

$$f(x)=\displaystyle {6x \over \sqrt{ 1+x^2}}$$

Ans: $\displaystyle {6 \over (1+x^2) \sqrt {1+x^2}} $

My problem is that after applying the quotient rule, i can't simplify it to the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = 6x(1+x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. Use product rule instead.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{split}
D_x\frac{6x} {\sqrt{ 1+x^2}}
&=
\frac{\sqrt{ 1+x^2}D_x6x-6xD_x\sqrt{ 1+x^2}} {1+x^2}
\\&=
\frac{\sqrt{ 1+x^2}6-6x\frac12(1+x^2)^{-1/2}2x} {1+x^2}
\\&=
(1+x^2)^{-1/2}\frac{(1+x^2)6-6x^2} {1+x^2}
\\&=
\frac{6} {(1+x^2)^{3/2}}
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Applying the quotient rule, you would end up with
$$f'(x)=\frac{(1+x^2)^{1/2}(6)-(6x)(1+x^2)^{-1/2}(x)}{(1+x^2)}$$ 
Multiplying both numerator and denominator by $(1+x^2)^{1/2}$ will result in
$$f'(x)=\frac{6(1+x^2)-6x^2}{(1+x^2)^{1/2}(1+x^2)}=\frac{6}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way using logarithmic differentiation $$f=\displaystyle {6x \over \sqrt{ 1+x^2}}$$ $$\log(f)=\log(6)+\log(x)-\frac 12 \log(1+x^2)$$  $$\frac{f'}f=\frac 1x-\frac 12\frac {2x}{1+x^2}=\frac 1x-\frac {x}{1+x^2}=\frac {1+x^2-x^2}{x(1+x^2)}=\frac {1}{x(1+x^2)}$$ So $$f'=\frac {1}{x(1+x^2)}\displaystyle {6x \over \sqrt{ 1+x^2}}=\frac 6 {(1+x^2)^{3/2}}$$